# Can someone direct me to a printer and/or scanner for digitizing books?

Tags: printer

The specs I am interested in would be that it's capable of a 1200 dpi dual-sided scanning of pages of all sizes, minimum size of preferably 6"x4" but at least a half sheet (8½" x 5½"), and the ADF would hold preferably 50 or more documents at a time.

The reason I want this is because I break down old books a digitize them. I use a heat gun to melt the glue on the binding. Then, I use a guillotine paper cutter to cut off the edges with glue on them, then I put them through the printer to digitize them. So, that's why I need the dual sided scanning from an ADF. The price range I am interested in is under $650.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are breaking the books apart, you are solving the most challenging aspect of such a project. Many all-in-one devices (printer, scanner, copier, fax) will perform double sided scanning. The 50 count requirement will winnow down your choices and may have fewer options that exclude the all-in-one models, but increase the price. Your budget isn't unreasonable.

A search using "double sided sheet fed scanner" provided a number of links with prices from a few hundred dollars up to nearly one thousand dollars. One of the links was a "the best..." type of page from PCmag.com which then led to an [HP scanner](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-scanjet-pro-2600-f1) with a 60 page capacity, single pass dual sided scanner, priced on the linked site for US$379, although you may find a less expensive source.

[image: HP double sided scanner]

The search took about 30 seconds to locate this item. Unless you have complications that prevent such a search, questions such as this risk being closed for lack of research.